# Element overflowing height of the page

Tags: html, css, hover, overflow

I'm working on a fixed `width` and `height` page.

I'm using a hover effects, but I have a problem as the `overflow-y` of the page is not fixed to `100vh` (100%).

Why does this happen and how can I solve this problem?

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.first {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(https://pixabay.com/get/9b249f09fa8c19807d92/1437036240/nature-213364_1280.jpg?direct);
  background-size: cover;
  float: left;
  transition: background-position 0.35s ease;
}
.second {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50vh;
  float: left;
  background-image: url(https://pixabay.com/get/5412212433a79f218468/1437036270/pyrenees-351266_1280.jpg?direct);
  background-size: cover;
}
.third {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50vh;
  float: left;
  background-image: url(https://pixabay.com/get/9480bb6112148d6fe514/1437036286/meadow-196567_1280.jpg?direct);
  background-size: cover;
}
.first:hover {
  background-position: 0 -60px;
  transition: background-position 0.35s ease;
}
/* EFFECT  1*/

div.effect-zoe figcaption {
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 47%;
  padding: 1.5%;
  background: #fff;
  color: #3c4a50;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
}
div.effect-zoe h2 {
  float: right;
  font-size: 24px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
div.effect-zoe p.icon-links a {
  float: right;
  color: #3c4a50;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
div.effect-zoe:hover p.icon-links a:hover,
div.effect-zoe:hover p.icon-links a:focus {
  color: #252d31;
}
div.effect-zoe p.description {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8em;
  padding: 2%;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: none;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: solid 1px #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* Fix for Chrome 37.0.2062.120 (Mac) */
}
div.effect-zoe h2 {
  display: inline-block;
}
div.effect-zoe:hover p.description {
  opacity: 1;
}
div.effect-zoe:hover figcaption,
div.effect-zoe:hover h2,
div.effect-zoe:hover p.icon-links a {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
div.effect-zoe:hover h2 {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.05s;
  transition-delay: 0.05s;
}
```

```html
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="first effect-zoe">
  <figcaption>
    <h2>VISITA IL SITO</h2>
    <p class="icon-links">
      <a href="#"><span class="icon-heart"></span></a>
      <a href="#"><span class="icon-eye"></span></a>
      <a href="#"><span class="icon-paper-clip"></span></a>
    </p>
    <p class="description"><strong>RIVIERA - HOME</strong><br/>Un luogo da cui partire, un luogo in cui far ritorno..</p>
  </figcaption>
</div>
<div class="second"></div>
<div class="third"></div>
```

Comment: Is all the CSS code necessary to reproduce your problem ? If not, please edit and simplify it, it will be better for peoples who wants to help you.

Comment: Yes u have right i simplify it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues that need to be addressed:

- By default `body` has `margin` applied by the browser. Remove this by adding `margin: 0;` to `body`
- The `height` of `.first` needs to be set not to expand if its content spills out. Do this by adding `overflow: hidden;` to `.first`
- `figcaption` needs to be positioned relatively to `.first`. Do this by adding `position: relative;` to `.first`
- As `.first` is now `position: relative;` `.top` will need to be modified to ensure it is positioned over it. Do this by adding `z-index: 1;` to `.top`
- Now that `figcaption` is relative to `.first` modify the `width` accordingly to fit. Change `width: 47%;` to `width: 97%;`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.top {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.first {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(https://pixabay.com/get/9b249f09fa8c19807d92/1437036240/nature-213364_1280.jpg?direct);
  background-size: cover;
  float: left;
  transition: background-position 0.35s ease;
}
.second {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50vh;
  float: left;
  background-image: url(https://pixabay.com/get/5412212433a79f218468/1437036270/pyrenees-351266_1280.jpg?direct);
  background-size: cover;
}
.third {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50vh;
  float: left;
  background-image: url(https://pixabay.com/get/9480bb6112148d6fe514/1437036286/meadow-196567_1280.jpg?direct);
  background-size: cover;
}
.first:hover {
  background-position: 0 -60px;
  transition: background-position 0.35s ease;
}
/* EFFECT  1*/

div.effect-zoe figcaption {
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 97%;
  padding: 1.5%;
  background: #fff;
  color: #3c4a50;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
}
div.effect-zoe h2 {
  float: right;
  font-size: 24px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
div.effect-zoe p.icon-links a {
  float: right;
  color: #3c4a50;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
div.effect-zoe:hover p.icon-links a:hover,
div.effect-zoe:hover p.icon-links a:focus {
  color: #252d31;
}
div.effect-zoe p.description {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8em;
  padding: 2%;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: none;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: solid 1px #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* Fix for Chrome 37.0.2062.120 (Mac) */
}
div.effect-zoe h2 {
  display: inline-block;
}
div.effect-zoe:hover p.description {
  opacity: 1;
}
div.effect-zoe:hover figcaption,
div.effect-zoe:hover h2,
div.effect-zoe:hover p.icon-links a {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
div.effect-zoe:hover h2 {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.05s;
  transition-delay: 0.05s;
}
```

```html
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="first effect-zoe">
  <figcaption>
    <h2>VISITA IL SITO</h2>
    <p class="icon-links">
      <a href="#"><span class="icon-heart"></span></a>
      <a href="#"><span class="icon-eye"></span></a>
      <a href="#"><span class="icon-paper-clip"></span></a>
    </p>
    <p class="description"><strong>RIVIERA - HOME</strong>
      <br/>Un luogo da cui partire, un luogo in cui far ritorno..
    </p>
  </figcaption>
</div>
<div class="second"></div>
<div class="third"></div>
```

Comment: It works really well!! thank You so much!!! so the main problem was the relative position of the main content ! and with "overflow : hidden " everything that's out to div will be not visible ... ty

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. Yes, those two are the main culprits. Without `position: relative;` on `.first` `figcaption` was being positioned relatively to the `body` instead.